# Since the capture and bubbling are executed successively, why the event will not respond twice?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Well I think you get my point which is all in the subject. I also attached a pic to make my question clear.

```
div.addEventListener('click', event=>alert('div'), true);
```

I clicked `button`, but the event on div only alert one time. The tutorial says capture and bubbling are executed successively, so I assume it went through phase 3 and phase 5, and the message will alert twice. However, clearly it just alerted one time... Why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your handler is set to capture the event only in its capturing phase, it won't fire in its bubbling phase.*
If you had

```
const cb = (evt) => alert(evt.eventPhase);
div.addEventListener('click', cb, true);
div.addEventListener('click', cb, false);
```

you would get `1` then `3`, which correspond to Event.CAPTURING_PHASE and Event.BUBBLING_PHASE respectively.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
const cb = (evt) => console.log( evt.eventPhase );
// we listen to the capturing phase
div.addEventListener("click", cb, { capture: true });
// and we listen to the bubbling phase
div.addEventListener("click", cb, { capture: false });
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Click me</div>
</div>
```

*<sub>Well there is the particular case of AT_TARGET where both handlers for capturing and bubbling will fire, in the order they were added.</sub>